# How to I use my init file to have another file automatically load in a buffer at start of emacs?

Tags: init-file

I want this file to show up in a buffer when I start emacs:

E:\emacs\org\index.org

What do I put in my init file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(find-file "E:/emacs/org/index.org")

Windows accepts both forward and backward slashes. I prefer forward slashes as they do not need escaping.

Comment: Double backslashes are necessary on Windows, otherwise Emacs will treat them as escape characters. Both double backslashes and single forward slashes work (and can be mixed in the same file path), but not single backslashes.